# Which Opensource products to use for Maprendering/Hosting?

Tags: web-mapping, mapserver, mapnik

I'm trying to setup a server for hosting maps for a gis application. The path I have taken so far is using an UBUNTU 10.04LTS installation. I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 and PostGIS 1.5. I already made a few attempts at using Mapnik and right now I'm struggling with TileCache to cache my maps.

I recently asked myself the question - why?
Has anyone got an overview with different server-tools to setup such a server. Why mapnik and not mapserver or why tilecache and not tirex etc. Is there a proven strategy or concept to follow?

My only information is in [this PDF](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=an%20efficient%20web-gis%20solution&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.fig.net/pub/fig2010/papers/ts05b%255Cts05b_miler_odobasic_et_al_4291.pdf&ei=1ybWTsKxHsGnsAbJ9-hi&usg=AFQjCNGyOhyVHM2_WCHhXZuh1ItRYAcX2A)

Right now, I just need to be able to host maps for my old prototype app in js/openlayers. I'd like be able to show that I am doing all I can now to help decide in which direction the appication I'm working on should go.

Thanks for your help!
Martin

Comment: I find this question too 'open'. Choosing one technology over another depends on a number of factors: personal tastes, the know-how already available in the organization, whether speed is that important...

Comment: can you narrow down your expectations - the question is too open currently...

Answer (score 1):

this is a good question but as dariapra and Mapperz have defined it is too open.
but i can give some information about my system.

first of all getting good performance for my system i use distributed architecture for mapping.

first machine which works on ubuntu (virtual machine) has web client project and postgresql and postgis extension .. in this machine i use apache web server.

second machine which works on ubuntu (virtual machine) has tile map service and its image  .. in this machine i use nginx web server. and really it shows good performance for lots of request.

third machine which worsk on windows has arcgis cache tiles .. in this machine iis is used for web server.

last machine which works on windows and has arcgis services(usually rest) for my application.

if you build one system which contains all app on, it will be crash after a short time because of lots of request ...

wishes to be useful..